# iPhone iOS custom UIButton with CAGradientLayer, how to make it indicate touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, cagradientlayer

I have a custom-styled UIButton within my view controllers that is achieved by customizing a UIButton with a CAGradientLayer, rounding corners and adding a border around the layer.
[image: Gradient button]

I like the look and feel of these buttons, and they are very easy to achieve too, without having to use pre-rendered images. But I'm having one problem - **such button does not respond to touch the way a UIButton does**. For example, a typical rounded rectangle button highlights blue when it is tapped, but my button does not.

**How can I achieve the "touch highlights button" behavior if I'm using custom `CAGradientLayer` backgrounds on a UIButton as per code below?**

Thank you for your input!

```
+(void)addLinearGradientToView:(UIView*)view TopColor:(UIColor*)topColor BottomColor:(UIColor*)bottomColor
{
    for(CALayer* layer in view.layer.sublayers)
    {
        if ([layer isKindOfClass:[CAGradientLayer class]])
        {
            [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
        }
    }
   CAGradientLayer* gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    //top down gradient
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1);
    gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds;



    gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[topColor CGColor], (id)[bottomColor CGColor], nil];

    [view.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];

}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you subclass UIButton you can override the `setHighlighted` method. Here you can set a different Gradient on the button, or change the background color.

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    // Update the looks of the button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop in your code will throw an error.

You should loop through the layers backwards like this

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [btn.layer.sublayers reverseObjectEnumerator];
for(CALayer *layer in enumerator) {
    if ([layer isKindOfClass:[CAGradientLayer class]])
    {
        [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
}
```